# DBCC Command Not being run by current user

Tags: sql-server-2016, dbcc, sql-standard

I have a stored Proc that runs a DBCC command CHECKIDENT 
The sproc is being run by a user with adequate permissions.
however, it is failing on the DBCC command with the error.

> User 'DifferentUser' does not have permission to run DBCC CHECKIDENT for object

I cannot figure out how this user is the one being used I have even removed this DifferentUser from the instance and all of the databases.

I am in a quandary

Comment: Please provide the Stored Procedure definition.

Comment: Did you tried executing it without SP `DBCC CHECKDB(DBName)`?

Comment: I am unable to provide the entire stored proc.  This is what I can provide

The sproc is run as the highest elevated RDS Admin account possible. The Sproc creates a temp table and then has DBCC CHECKIDENT for the identity

then fails saying some obscure user doesn't have permissions.  The user account has been completely removed from the instance but it is still giving the same error.

I have run the process as a sproc and as just a sql statement.